# X509Certificate2 the server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key

Tags: ssl, x509certificate2, sslstream, makecert

I use SslStream to build a web server.  However, the code below throws an exception when AuthenticateAsServer.

```
static X509Certificate cert;
protected virtual Stream GetStream(TcpClient client)
{
        var ss = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        if (cert == null)
        {
            cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile("test.cer");
        }
        ss.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, true);
        return ss;
}
```

I've already used X509Certificate2 to load the cert file why it still throw the exception (**The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key**)?

The cert file was created using the following command:

```
makecert    
    -pe                                     Exportable private key
    -n "CN=localhost"                       Subject name
    -ss my                                  Certificate store name
    -sr LocalMachine                        Certificate store location
    -a sha1                                 Signature algorithm
    -sky signature                          Subject key type is for signature purposes
    -r                                      Make a self-signed cert
    "test.cer"                            Output filename
```

Answer (score 6):

```
makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=localhost" -sky exchange -sv server.pvk server.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx -pi <password>

var certificate = new X509Certificate("path\server.pfx", "password");
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine, I had to use new X509Certificate2 though (not X509Certificate)

Comment: `Error: Unable to create file for the subject ('server.pvk')`. Windows has a UI for everything, they couldn't make a button to this in 1 second?