# Why would SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer fail from Ubuntu but not from Windows 10

Tags: c#, ubuntu, authentication, .net-core, sslstream

The SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer method fails from Ubuntu but not from Windows 10.

When implementing the SslStrem example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8
It runs fine when executed on Windows 10, but when executed on Ubuntu I get the following exception when `sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer` is called:

> System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a
>   certificate with the associated private key.

I've tried using `serverCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(certificate)` instead of `serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate)` but to no avail.

The certificates are generated with OpenSSL and when performing the modulus check all keys and certificates do in fact match.  The server certificate is signed with the CA certificate.  The certificates are generated using [jww's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) lengthy answer at [How do you sign a Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority)

So to summerise: When calling sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer on **Ubuntu** (but not on Windows 10) the following exception is thrown: System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.

I'm using the .net-core environment (obviously necessary to run on Linux) :-)

It's not the same as the suggested possible duplicate [X509Certificate2 the server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615062/x509certificate2-the-server-mode-ssl-must-use-a-certificate-with-the-associated) because it answers how the certificate is generated.  However, [drake7707's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694640/drake7707) reply to [Mark Yuan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2673228/mark-yuan) answer gave me a hint.

So the problem is solved as follows:
Replace the line of code

```
serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate);
```

with

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
```

and change its declaration from

```
static X509Certificate serverCertificate = null;
```

to

```
static X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = null;
```

So in summary, using `X509Certificate2` does, in fact, solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X509Certificate2 the server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615062/x509certificate2-the-server-mode-ssl-must-use-a-certificate-with-the-associated)

Comment: I appreciate that you have solved the issue, but looking at the exception message ("**System.NotSupportedException**: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key." - emphasis is mine) in combination with the [apisof page for AuthenticateAsServer](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(X509Certificate)) shows that it's not supported on OSs other than Windows

Comment: I guess that's why `X509Certificate2` was written because `X509Certificate` does not support other OSs.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is solved as follows:
Replace the line of code

```
serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate);
```

with

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
```

and change its declaration from

```
static X509Certificate serverCertificate = null;
```

to

```
static X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = null;
```

So in summary, using `X509Certificate2` does, in fact, solve the problem.

Comment: Post the answer as an *answer* instead. Few (if any) will notice that the second part of the question is actually the answer. Check [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)