# Can't get C# SslStream to work with my X509 certs

Tags: c#, ssl, x509

I am kind of new to doing security and encryption, so if I just made a very dumb mistake, sorry in advance.
I need a server and a client communicating through a secure connection using SslStream. But my certificates don't work. I get the following error: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.'`
My code was the microsoft example given in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8ss

I tried:

- Self singed certs using makecert (Like in this post: [SSLStream example - how do I get certificates that work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982865/sslstream-example-how-do-i-get-certificates-that-work))
- Certificates with OpenSSL
- The procedure on this website: http://www.reliablesoftware.com/DasBlog/PermaLink,guid,6507b2c6-473e-4ddc-9e66-8a161e5df6e9.aspx
- Using the .pfx file instead of the .cer file (like in this post:[X509Certificate2 the server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615062/x509certificate2-the-server-mode-ssl-must-use-a-certificate-with-the-associated)), but got the following exception: `Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.`

All except the last one gave the `System.NotSupportedException: 'The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.'` exception.
Does this mean that self-signed certificates don't work? Do I need to buy a certificate?

Edit:
Here is the code I used. It is the modified example (Sorry if it is terribly coded on my part) and is executable, simulating server and client and throws the exception:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Temporarily added the arguments here for you to see
        args = new string[2] { @"C:\Users\jacke\Documents\CA\TempCert.cer", "FakeServerName" };
        Console.WriteLine("Starting server in seperate thread...");
        Task t = Task.Run(() => { Server.Initialize(args[0]); });
        Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        Client.RunClient(args[1]);
    }
}

public static class Server
{
    private static X509Certificate cert;
    private static TcpListener server;

    public static void Initialize(string certificate)
    {
        cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate);
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12321);
        server.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");

            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            ProcessClient(client);
        }
    }


    private static void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
    {

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, clientCertificateRequired: false, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;   
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client message...");
            string messageData = Helpers.ReadMessage(sslStream);
            byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the server.<EOF>");
            Console.WriteLine("Sending hello message.");
            sslStream.Write(message);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        finally
        {                
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }



}

public static class Client
{
    private static Hashtable certificateErrors = new Hashtable();
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
          object sender,
          X509Certificate certificate,
          X509Chain chain,
          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
        return false;
    }


    public static void RunClient(string serverName)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 12321);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null
            );
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the client.<EOF>");
        sslStream.Write(messsage);
        string serverMessage = Helpers.ReadMessage(sslStream);
        Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", serverMessage);

        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Client closed.");
    }


}

public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        // Read the  message sent by the server.
        // The end of the message is signaled using the
        // "<EOF>" marker.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
            // Check for EOF.
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes != 0);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here is how I created the certificates (as explained in the post I linked above):

```
makecert -sv RootCATest.pvk -r -n "CN=FakeServerName" RootCATest.cer
makecert -ic RootCATest.cer -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=FakeServerName" -sv
TempCert.pvk -pe -sky exchange TempCert.cer
cert2spc TempCert.cer TempCert.spc
pvkimprt -pfx TempCert.spc TempCert.pvk
```

Additional information I entered with the commands above:

- When asked for a by the first 2 commands password I left it blank
- I checked export private key and set 'A' as a password for the last command

Then I imported the .pfx file in the local certificate store (I also tried machine wide earlier) and let the program pick the right store. It warned me that all certificates by the CA will be trusted and I should contact the CA to check this was indeed their certificate, but I proceeded. Then I ran the code (using the 'TempCert.cer' file I just created) and got the error. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: It would be great if you could post your source code. What is the server application? Is it a web application hosted on a web server? Or is it part of your implementation?

Comment: Welcome to so. Please provide more information on what you already tried and where you failed. You wrote that you created a certificate with makecert / openssl, please provide the commands you used. Also provide a [mcve] of your code with an exact error message that you got.

Comment: as @OguzOzgul said, it will be so much better if you post your actual code and the errors you are getting...

Comment: I am very sorry. I used the code in the microsoft example, but I will provide a minimal reproducible example as quickly as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, a `.cer` file does not include a private key, and *I assume* by loading a certificate from file the certificate store is not checked. You could export a `.pfx` and include the private key in the export.

I don't know why the `.pvk` attempt failed though (never tried that format myself) - `SslStream` can definitely work with self-signed certificates; the client side just has to ignore the validation failure.

However if you've already imported it into the store, you should be able to load it directly:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

// ...

using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "FakeServerName", false);
    return new X509Certificate2(certs[0]);
}
```

Respoding to the error in your comment:

> The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

I don't know if I got exactly that message, but I do remember having to grant access to the user the app runs into. You'd have to open the *correct* certificates tool:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in
(run mmc, select file/add snap-in, choose certificates)

Then grant user(s) access to the private key:

https://docs.secureauth.com/display/KBA/Grant+Permission+to+Use+Signing+Certificate+Private+Key
(right click the certificate, select all tasks/manage private keys)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so quickly! I tried to just paste the code into my program and replace old the initialization of the certificate with this one, but I got the following exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized'. I confused the .pvk file with the .pfx file in my original question (my apologies), so I actually tried the .pfx (as shown in the link I provided) and it got the Exception I described under that point. Thanks a lot anyways, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Updated my answer, I'm afraid that's all my experience in the subject and I don't have any background information on any of this. You could also try running with administrator privileges to diagnose further. If this doesn't help, hopefully this at least gets you some new ideas on how to continue.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Marking my user as being allowed to see the certificate like you described finally resolved my issue!